# Is there a way to make a computer boot when plugged in(or power returns after an outage)?

Tags: boot, automation, power, netbook

I've been using a little netbook as a personal server for 2 years give or take a few months, but soon I'll be going off to college. I plan on leaving it at my house, but if the power goes out I won't be there to turn it back on if the battery dies while the power is out.

Are there any ways to make it boot autonomously after an outage, or make it consume little to no power when not plugged in?

It looks like it's an 'Acer Aspire one series zg5', and it's running Ubuntu 11.04 server edition.

Comment: I don't know about your laptop, but my previous and current desktop have a BIOS option to do just that (auto power on after unexpected loss of power). So perhaps take a look there (I doubt a laptop will have that option, though).

Comment: Oh and a small piece of advice: during that time you are away don't forget that the computer will accumulate dust. Specially since it is a netbook, and a netbook that is working 24/7, you should definitely clean it after some time.

Answer (score 11):

Usually there is. Look in the BIOS settings for Power Options, and find a "Action when lost power" or similar. Change it to  "Last State" *or* "Power On".

Your BIOS may or may not have it depending on bios manufacturer.